# File in use after AppleScript duplication

Tags: applescript

I have a script that runs every two hours. It copies a Helix database collection and its log file to a local backup folder. I first save, so they are in sync, then copy them both. It has started failing intermittently, saying that the log file is in use. It's dimmed in the Finder.

Here's the script:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set dupArray to {}
    --move the collection into the array
    set CollectionName to name of collectionFile
    copy collectionFile to the end of dupArray

    --move the logfile into the array
    set theCollectionLogfile to ((mainLoc as text) & "Log_" & CollectionName & ".hlog")
    if (exists file theCollectionLogfile) then
        copy theCollectionLogfile to the end of dupArray
    end if

    --do the duplicate
    duplicate dupArray to backupFolder with replacing
end tell
```

How can I get it to duplicate with replacing that second time?

Thanks

Lenny

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:
**I suggest you save your work and test vigorously so you get these concepts.**
And please read completely.

[**EDIT:** I realize, even though you probably understood what I meant, that I wrote "copy" when I meant to write "duplicate" in the comments]

You might try using something like the following:

```
--right before duplicate
set UNIQUE_fileName to "Log_" & CollectionName & ".hlog"
repeat until fileNotInUse
    try
        do shell script "lsof | grep " & UNIQUE_fileName
    on error
        set fileNotInUse to true
        exit repeat
    end try
end repeat
--do duplicate
```

This should wait until the file is done being written to. You'll notice I am capitalizing UNIQUE because if there are ANY other files matching that name in use by the system, or whatever, it will put you in an infinite loop. One way to avoid this is to pass the POSIX style full path of the file instead of just the name. You can also be extra careful by putting an upper limit for the repeat. Here's a version using both ideas:

```
--right before duplicate

set upperLimit to 200000
set u to 0

set theCollectionLogfilePOSIX to quoted form of (POSIX path of theCollectionLogfile)
repeat until fileNotInUse
    try
        do shell script "lsof | grep " & theCollectionLogfilePOSIX
    on error
        set fileNotInUse to true
        exit repeat
    end try
set u to (u + 1)
if (u > upperLimit) then exit repeat
end repeat
--do duplicate
```

***Again:***

**I suggest you save your work and test vigorously so you get the concepts.**

[EDIT: it's in a try block because if there's nothing 'open' (that is, nothing being 'grepped' from the lsof result), the do shell script will error]

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was out yesterday... Unfortunately, a day later, this file is still "in use". It's not releasing for anything

Comment: I take it you get that I meant "duplicate" where I wrote "copy"; this was intended to be before the last duplicate part.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally bit the bullet and just wrote it in 'do shell script'. Turns out the Finder didn't want to throw out the file, it was still hooked to something. I used ditto for duplicating (because the files have resource forks), and I used rm for deleting the file.

I think the Finder messed up and locked something because the files I was duplicating have open sockets while I am doing it. I also think the Get Ifo dialog should have an area where you can see what app is using something if it says is "in Use".

Thanks for the help...

Lenny